# Top vs latest tweets in new Twitter accounts

Tags: twitter

I joined Twitter in 2009. In my home page I always see the "latest tweets". A friend that has joined about a year ago has two options - latest tweets and "top tweets", where it shows the (presumed) important tweets first.

I want to also switch to this view, but it doesn't exist anywhere. What I am missing?